# NullPointerException in ActivityThread.handleBindApplication

Tags: android

I have received this stack trace report that does not mention my app at all:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3979)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anybody have any idea how to prevent this exception?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: There is no mention of my app in the stack trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always when this happens I have to dig through the Android source to assess the problem, and I thought I would post my findings here so it would save others time.

This error corresponds to this code in [**4.1.1_r1**](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java/#3979) and [**4.1.2_r1**](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java/#3979):

```
    final ContextImpl appContext = new ContextImpl();
    appContext.init(data.info, null, this);
    final File cacheDir = appContext.getCacheDir();

    // Provide a usable directory for temporary files
    System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", cacheDir.getAbsolutePath()); // line 3979

    setupGraphicsSupport(data.info, cacheDir);
```

This is happening because [`appContext.getCacheDir()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.getCacheDir%28%29) returns null in some instances:

```
@Override
public File getCacheDir() {
    synchronized (mSync) {
        if (mCacheDir == null) {
            mCacheDir = new File(getDataDirFile(), "cache");
        }
        if (!mCacheDir.exists()) {
            if(!mCacheDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to create cache directory");
                return null;
            }
            FileUtils.setPermissions(
                    mCacheDir.getPath(),
                    FileUtils.S_IRWXU|FileUtils.S_IRWXG|FileUtils.S_IXOTH,
                    -1, -1);
        }
    }
    return mCacheDir;
}
```

Related:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/-694j87eXVU

---

However this *seems* to be being handled properly in version **4.2.1**:

```
    final ContextImpl appContext = new ContextImpl();
    appContext.init(data.info, null, this);
    if (!Process.isIsolated()) {
        final File cacheDir = appContext.getCacheDir();

        if (cacheDir != null) {
            // Provide a usable directory for temporary files
            System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", cacheDir.getAbsolutePath());

            setupGraphicsSupport(data.info, cacheDir);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to setupGraphicsSupport due to missing cache directory");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally find I get these kind of exceptions when a service, activity or whatever has problems initiating itself. Typically I have done something bad (TM) in my variable initiations in the class or I have done something else bad to the layout or views I am instantiating. I would start by looking at what is being started up at the time this happens.

Another easy way to trigger this kind of exception is to call and activity (or service etc) without having declared it as such in the manifest. Or try to do something that requires a permission and forget to declare that (although it doesn't look like that error in this case).

Comment: Well I can't actually reproduce the error, it has just been reported a couple of times on an app that has several thousands sessions a day. But as you can see from the stack trace I can't even pinpoint an activity to focus on.

Comment: Pants - I hate that - I have a similar crash sitting around on an app waiting to be resolved. I can't even find a version of android which has a believable line of code for line the stack trace crashes at. Have any of the error reports given an android version or other user feedback?

Comment: No there is no device, android version, or user feedback. Just this stack trace. I think I will have to just ignore the error.

Comment: Sounds like it. One odd one I've come across - might you be using a variable (or class) created in service or activity A in the creation of class B after A might have been cleaned up?

Comment: I don't think so, I think from the Android source I posted below it seems that this is Android bug because they are relying on `getCacheDir()` to return some not null value when there are clear instances when it returns a `null`.